# Trouble triggering password save with redux forms on iOS Safari

Tags: reactjs, redux, autocomplete, redux-form, react-redux-form

My project uses redux-forms and I am trying to get autocomplete working on the login and register form. I have followed all the docs I could find on autocomplete and it works for every browser but iOS Safari.

I have added all the applicable autocomplete attributes and the form is submitting like it should. When the user finishes the login or register, then goes to interact with the page in another way, it works fine. With that in mind, I tried a couple things to force it to pop up. On attempted login, I rerouted the user. Nothing. I popped up an alert. Nothing. and now, I am here!

Login Form:

```
<form onSubmit={this.login.bind(this)} autoComplete="on">
                <Field
                  component={TextField}
                  id="email"
                  fullWidth
                  autoComplete="email"
                  hintText="Email"
                  name="email"
                  type="email"
                  normalize={R.toLower}
                  validate={[required, email]}
                  {...FormElements.styles.text}
                />
                <Field
                  id="password"
                  autoFocus={!!login_email}
                  component={TextField}
                  fullWidth
                  autoComplete="current-password"
                  hintText="Password"
                  name="password"
                  type="password"
                  onKeyPress={this.passwordOnKeyPressHandler.bind(this)}
                  validate={[required]}
                  {...FormElements.styles.text}
                />
                {error && <div className="form-error m-t">{error}</div>}
                <div className="text-center m-t">
                  <div className="m-b-sm">
                    Don&apos;t have an account?{" "}
                    <a
                      className="register-link"
                      href="javascript:void(0)"
                      onClick={() =>
                        this.props.toggle(this.props.VIEWS.REGISTER)
                      }
                    >
                      Register
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div className="">
                    <a
                      className="forgot-password-link"
                      href="javascript:void(0)"
                      onClick={() => this.props.toggle(this.props.VIEWS.FORGOT)}
                    >
                      forgot password?
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="register__footer visible-md visible-lg">
                  {this.renderBtn({ size: "large" })}
                </div>
                <div className="auth__switch-view visible-xs visible-sm">
                  <div className="m-t">{this.renderBtn()}</div>
                </div>
              </form>
```

button:

```
<div className="register__action-btn-container">
        <Button
          type="submit"
          disabled={submitting}
          label={submitting ? "Logging in ..." : "Login"}
          size={params && params.size}
        />
      </div>
```

login function:

```
 login(e) {
    // e.preventDefault();
    document.querySelector('input[name="password"]').blur();
    // this.props.handleSubmit();
    $S.dispatch(submit(LOGIN_FORM));
    // On mobile, we have to force the username and password to be stored.
    miscUtils.triggerSavePasswordPrompt(e);
  }
```

Trying to force it...

```
function triggerSavePasswordPrompt(event) {
  if (window.PasswordCredential && event) {
    let c = new PasswordCredential(event.target);
    navigator.credentials.store(c);
  } else {
    alert("shizs effed yo")
  }
}
```

I expect the prompt to show up to save or suggest a password when the user submits on iOS Safari. It does not. However, it will show the autofill prompt if the user DOES have a saved password.

Comment: Edit: I am aware that the new PasswordCredential function wont take a form. This is not applicable to safari as it doesn't support this function anyway

Comment: So, routing to a different page entirely works as well. Thats not really an option for UX on our site, but it gives me some insight into what safari wants to see to count it as a "savable password"

Comment: Did you ever have any luck triggering the password save dialog from React?  I'm trying to figure it out now and surprised at how little documentation there is about it.